# AS3 Flash CS5 - XML node filters?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I did find this piece of code (slightly edited):

```
var destinations:XML = <destinations>
       <destination location="japan">
        <exchangeRate>400</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Samurai History</placesOfInterest>
    </destination>   
    <destination location="australia">
        <exchangeRate>140</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Surf and BBQ</placesOfInterest>
    </destination>
    <destination location="peru">
        <exchangeRate>30</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Food</placesOfInterest>
    </destination>
</destinations>;

//FILTER BY ATTRIBUTE NAME  -------------------
var filteredByLocation:XMLList = destinations.destination.(@location == "japan");
trace("Attribute Name: "+filteredByLocation);

//FILTER BY NODE VALUE ----------------------
var filteredByExchangeRate:XMLList = destinations.destination.(exchangeRate < 200);
trace("Node Value: "+filteredByExchangeRate);
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to do the opposite. I mean, get everything but not the node with the attribute name.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `destinations.destination.(@location != "japan");`

Comment: Thanks @putvande. I did test it minutes ago. I think I must avoid asking questions sleepy.

Answer (score 0):

I was too sleepy:

```
//FILTER BY ATTRIBUTE NAME  -------------------
var filteredByLocation:XMLList = destinations.destination.(@location != "japan");
trace("Attribute Name: "+filteredByLocation);
```

Anyway, it can be useful for someone there.